# How to avoid reading whitespace in C++ text read

Tags: c++, readfile

I am reading a text file which is written by a earlier routine. The text file contains the id and the path of certain data that i am processing. Because when i write to text file i used `<<endl;` to go to the next line hence when i read the text file again it reads the white space. And the problem gets serious when i loop over again creating muliple whitespace and therefore i read and process garbage.

```
inFile.getline(buffer, 255);
string line(buffer);
istringstream iss_(line);
string index;
iss_ >> index;
index.push_back(index); // vector
```

my input text is generated after some process that contains list of text file directory and id.
eg. D /Users/Student/Desktop/data1.txt
    S /Users/Student/Desktop/data2.txt

How can i avoid reading whitespace in C++?

Comment: Exactly what does your input look like, and can you provide more details of what goes wrong? [And I'm pretty sure `index.push_back(index)` isn't something you really do in your actual code].

Comment: C++ `operator>>` to `std:: string` skips leading whitespace and terminates after non-whitespace content by default... just use `while (inFile >> myString) ...`.

Comment: If you do end up using line by line input, may I recommend replacing [`std::basic_istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) with [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) that reads to a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). This avoids worrying about the buffer yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`istream::ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)  or [`skipws`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/skipws/).